# Syntax checker pointing some errors I don't know why

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm updated Eclipse CDT to 9.8.1, and syntax checker started to point out some errors which aren't so.  In this example, `p3Dw` and `Ow` are `cv::Mat` objects, syntax checker underlines `PO` as "Invalid arguments":

```
cv::Mat PO = p3Dw-Ow;


Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
 Mat()
 Mat(int, int, int)
 Mat(int, int, int, const cv::Scalar_<double> &)
 Mat(cv::Size_<int>, int)
 Mat(cv::Size_<int>, int, const cv::Scalar_<double> &)
 Mat(int, const int *, int)
 Mat(int, const int *, int, const cv::Scalar_<double> &)
 Mat(const std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>> &, int)
 Mat(const std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>> &, int, const cv::Scalar_<double> &)
 Mat(const cv::Mat &)
 Mat(int, int, int, void *, unsigned long int)
 Mat(cv::Size_<int>, int, void *, unsigned long int)
 Mat(const std::vector<#0,std::allocator<#0>> &, bool)
 Mat(std::initializer_list<#0>)
 Mat(std::initializer_list<int>, std::initializer_list<#0>)
 Mat(const std::array<#0,unsigned long int3 #1 0> &, bool)
 Mat(const cv::Vec<#0,int3 #1 0> &, bool)
 Mat(const cv::Matx<#0,int3 #1 0,int3 #2 0> &, bool)
 Mat(const cv::Point_<#0> &, bool)
 Mat(const cv::Point3_<#0> &, bool)
 Mat(const cv::MatCommaInitializer_<#0> &)
 Mat(const cv::Mat &, const cv::Range &, const cv::Range &)
 Mat(const cv::Mat &, const cv::Rect_<int> &)
 Mat(const cv::Mat &, const cv::Range *)
 Mat(const cv::Mat &, const std::vector<cv::Range,std::allocator<cv::Range>> &)
 Mat(cv::Mat &&)
 Mat(int, const int *, int, void *, const unsigned long int *)
 Mat(const std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>> &, int, void *, const unsigned long int *)
 Mat(const cv::cuda::GpuMat &)
'
```

It happens only when assigning a Mat on declaration, with a MatExpr.  It doesn't happen otherwise: you can declare a Mat assigning another Mat, or assign a MatExpr to a Mat previously declared.

This code was working for years.  Right now I'm messing with it and I won't be able to compile it for a while.

I cleaned the project and rebuild the index, with no improvement.

There are other strange misleading errors.  using namespace std; the checker mark vector and unique_lock as error, unless I add std::

Any thoughts?  Thank you.

Comment: Do you pass different flag? Does code compile and it is "just" IDE error?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, I appreciate your concern.  Right now the code doesn't compile, and throws these errors among other.  So, it's not just the parser.  The only flag is -std=c++17

Comment: I guess that comment was for @Jarod42? :-) Anyway, have you upgraded `opencv` since you last compiled the program?

Comment: Yes, it was for Jarod42!  If I code like I write comments, it would explain many things...  :)  No, I was using opencv4 for a while, with this and other projects, working fine.

Comment: It was an eclipse cdt bug, already fixed.  This question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57626348/eclipse-cdt-syntax-error-parser-false-error-with-mat-assignment-it-compiles-and/57634555#57634555

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the free function `MatExpr operator-(const Mat &a, const Mat &b);` function and an assignment operator `Mat& Mat::operator=(const MatExpr &expr);` in the `opencv4` documentation, but no `Mat` constructor accepting a `MatExpr`.

There is however a conversion operator: `cv::MatExpr::operator Mat() const;` which *should* make your code work, and it *does* work in opencv 3.4.4. Minimal example:

```
#include <opencv2/core/mat.hpp> // it is really opencv 3.4.4

int main() {
    cv::Mat p3Dw;
    cv::Mat Ow;
    cv::Mat PO = p3Dw-Ow;
}
```

If it doesn't work in opencv 4, they may have made the copy constructor `explicit` (even though it's not in the manual). If so, cast the `MatExpr` to a `Mat`:

```
cv::Mat PO = static_cast<cv::Mat>(p3Dw-Ow);
```

Comment: Now I strongly believe it has nothing to do with opencv, but with the ide.  Thank you.