# Eclipse CDT syntax error parser false error with Mat assignment: It compiles and runs ok

Tags: opencv, eclipse-cdt

In this line of code, the x is red underlined as error:

```
cv::Mat x = cv::Mat::eye(2,2,CV_8U);
```

with this description:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
 Mat()
 Mat(int, int, int)
 Mat(int, int, int, const cv::Scalar_<double> &)
 ... (it goes on, full error description at the bottom)
```

It compiles and runs ok.

```
09:12:02 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 1s.721ms)
```

It used to work fine.  I can't tell exactly when this started, but in the middle I updated Eclipse to the last stable version Version: *2019-06 (4.12.0) Build id: 20190614-1200.*

It's something with the parser.  I'm using elf-parser as error parser (the default configuration for Linux).  I tried with c++11 and c++17, and without telling which C++ to use.

The generic false error happens when assigning a `MatExpr` to a `Mat` declaration.  `MatExpr` is supposed to be automatically cast to `Mat` (like it always did).  It's too specific to opencv, but sometimes error parser fails to recognize `std::endl`, so I believe the problem with the parser isn't specific to opencv.

Full error description for completeness, I'm pretty sure there is nothing relevant here:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
 Mat()
 Mat(int, int, int)
 Mat(int, int, int, const cv::Scalar_<double> &)
 Mat(cv::Size_<int>, int)
 Mat(cv::Size_<int>, int, const cv::Scalar_<double> &)
 Mat(int, const int *, int)
 Mat(int, const int *, int, const cv::Scalar_<double> &)
 Mat(const std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>> &, int)
 Mat(const std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>> &, int, const cv::Scalar_<double> &)
 Mat(const cv::Mat &)
 Mat(int, int, int, void *, unsigned long int)
 Mat(cv::Size_<int>, int, void *, unsigned long int)
 Mat(const std::vector<#0,std::allocator<#0>> &, bool)
 Mat(std::initializer_list<#0>)
 Mat(std::initializer_list<int>, std::initializer_list<#0>)
 Mat(const std::array<#0,unsigned long int3 #1 0> &, bool)
 Mat(const cv::Vec<#0,int3 #1 0> &, bool)
 Mat(const cv::Matx<#0,int3 #1 0,int3 #2 0> &, bool)
 Mat(const cv::Point_<#0> &, bool)
 Mat(const cv::Point3_<#0> &, bool)
 Mat(const cv::MatCommaInitializer_<#0> &)
 Mat(const cv::Mat &, const cv::Range &, const cv::Range &)
 Mat(const cv::Mat &, const cv::Rect_<int> &)
 Mat(const cv::Mat &, const cv::Range *)
 Mat(const cv::Mat &, const std::vector<cv::Range,std::allocator<cv::Range>> &)
 Mat(cv::Mat &&)
 Mat(int, const int *, int, void *, const unsigned long int *)
 Mat(const std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>> &, int, void *, const unsigned long int *)
 Mat(const cv::cuda::GpuMat &)
'
```

Comment: Can you provide some context like what `#include` statements are necessary for the names in the mentioned line of code to resolve?

Comment: I figured it out: `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`. For future reference, though, it makes life easier for people if you include a complete source file.

Comment: You're right, I should have realized that.  It is `#include <opencv2/core.hpp>`, pretty much the same you figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Eclipse's C++ parser, filed as [bug 550397](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=550397).

**UPDATE**: I also have a fix for it.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I was running out of ideas, looking for an error in my configuration.  I am impressed how you manage to generalize to "Error resolving overloaded conversion operators when one of them is a template".  And the bug is already found, that was fast.